# Need guidance with array lists

Tags: java, arrays

How would i go around getting my txt to output the following format ! It only outputs the first line i input but would like it look like the following>>

This is an example of how I would like an output to look - https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lfr0.png

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io[enter image description here][1].PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class GAMESCORE {

private static char[] input;

public static void main(String[] args) {



        int[] minutesPlayed = new int [100];
        String gamerName, gamerReport;


        String[] gameNames = new String[100];
        int[] highScores = new int[100];

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("-------------- Game Score Report Generator --------------");
        System.out.println("     ");


        System.out.println("Enter Your Name");
        gamerName = Scan.nextLine();
        boolean isEmpty = gamerName == null || gamerName.trim().length() == 0;

        if (isEmpty) {

            System.out.print("Enter your Name.");

            gamerName = Scan.nextLine();
        }



        System.out.println("Enter details in this format - " + " -->");
        System.out.println("    ");



        System.out.println("Game : Achievement Score : Minutes Played");
        gamerReport = Scan.nextLine();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);     

        List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();    
        String word;                                  
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {               
          word = scanner.nextLine();                  
          if (word != null) {                        
            word = word.trim();                      
            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {      
              break;                                  
            }
            al.add(word);                             
          } else {
            break;                                    
}
        }


        String[] splitUpReport; 
        splitUpReport = gamerReport.split(":"); 

        int i = 0;


        gameNames[i] = splitUpReport[0];
        highScores[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitUpReport[1].trim() );
        minutesPlayed[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitUpReport[2].trim());




        try
       {

           PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Gaming Report Data.txt", true));
           writer.println("Player : " + gamerName);
           writer.println();
           writer.println("--------------------------------");
           writer.println();
           String[] report = gamerReport.split(":");
           writer.println("Game: " + report[0] + ", score= " +report[1] + ", minutes played= " +report[2]);
           //writer.println("Games Played : " + minutesPlayed);
           writer.close();





       } catch (IOException e)
       {
           System.err.println("You have made an error with data input");
       }



System.out.println("You have quit!");
           }





public static char[] getInput() {
    return input;
}

public static void setInput(char[] input) {
    GAMESCORE.input = input;
}

}
```

Comment: would like it look like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lfr0.png

Comment: Your question is too generic. Break it down into a specific issue. with only a few lines of code. What exactly are you trying to do with your Arraylist? At the moment your array list is never used apart from storing text, then you never do anything with it. Try using the Arraylist after your while loop. See here for more help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the variable "gamerReport" is set for the first line, and is never touched again other than to print it, and the list "al" has stuff added to it, but is never used. Maybe try something like this?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class GAMESCORE {

private static char[] input;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int totalGames, totalAchievements, totalTime;

    totalGames = 0;
    totalAchievements = 0;
    totalTime = 0;

    String gamerName, gamerReport;

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("-------------- Game Score Report Generator --------------");
    System.out.println("     ");


    System.out.println("Enter Your Name");
    gamerName = Scan.nextLine();
    boolean isEmpty = gamerName == null || gamerName.trim().length() == 0;

    if (isEmpty) {

        System.out.print("Enter your Name.");

        gamerName = Scan.nextLine();
    }



    System.out.println("Enter details in this format - " + " -->");
    System.out.println("    ");



    System.out.println("Game : Achievement Score : Minutes Played");
    gamerReport = Scan.nextLine();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    String word;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        word = scanner.nextLine();
        if (word != null) {
            word = word.trim();
            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                break;
            }
            al.add(word);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }




    try
    {

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Gaming Report Data.txt", true));

        writer.println("Player : " + gamerName);
        writer.println();
        writer.println("--------------------------------");
        writer.println();
        for(String listString : al){
            String[] splitUpReport;
            splitUpReport = listString.split(":");

            writer.println("Game: " + splitUpReport[0].trim() + ", score= " + splitUpReport[1].trim() + ", minutes played= " +splitUpReport[2].trim());

            totalGames++;
            totalTime += Integer.parseInt(splitUpReport[2].trim());
            totalAchievements += Integer.parseInt(splitUpReport[1].trim());
        }

        writer.println();
        writer.println("--------------------------------");
        writer.println();
        writer.println("Games Played: " + String.valueOf(totalGames));
        writer.println("Total Achievement: " + String.valueOf(totalAchievements));
        writer.println("Total Time: " + String.valueOf(totalTime) + " (" + String.valueOf(totalTime/60) + " hours and " + String.valueOf(totalTime%60) + " minutes)");
        //writer.println("Games Played : " + minutesPlayed);
        writer.close();





    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("You have made an error with data input");
    }



    System.out.println("You have quit!");
}





public static char[] getInput() {
    return input;
}

public static void setInput(char[] input) {
    GAMESCORE.input = input;
}

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much that i has sorted one of my problems. however i have another where it is on outputting the first input and not any others, http://tinypic.com/r/2mmi8e8/9 and http://tinypic.com/r/2621k4n/9 @stephen

Comment: its not outputting the first one, it outputs the rest except the first one with the code you have provided!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot. Just remove the "gamerReport = Scan.next.Line();" line.

Comment: any ideas on how to output the the player name , game score and time to the console ??? @stephen

Comment: Oh yeah, just do the code from the writer section, and replace writer.println with system.out.println

Comment: By the way, what is this for? It seems like an interesting project.